# Is there a way to preserve paragraphs when importing Event descriptions using API csv Import?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, import

First of all - the API csv Import extension is terrific. It's going to really help me out with something.

I am importing webform submissions in order to create Events in CiviCRM, and it's working wonderfully with one minor exception. Paragraphs in textarea webform fields are getting turned into a single paragraph. It's not the end of the world, but I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to preserve the paragraphs.

Thank you.

Drupal 7.41
CiviCRM 4.6.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this using this module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_html_textarea

Used an html textarea field on my form instead of plain text. The field gets submitted with html markup which preserves the paragraphs.